# flex passing data to multiple views

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

am building mobile flex application , that has 1 main view that .contain the list of names and 2 detail views ( one view in English and second detail in Arabic).

when i run the program and choose something from the list it would show the first detail view with some English text then when i click on switch button to it shows empty text area.

pushview in main view :

```
protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            navigator.pushView(Details,list.selectedItem);
        }
```

push view in 2nd view :

```
<s:Button label="switch"  click="navigator.pushView(ArabicDetails)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to expand the data you're pushing into the views. For example, you push the `selectedItem` into the `Details` view.  Instead you could push an object like this:

```
{ selectedItem: list.selectedItem,
  englishDetails: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
  arabicDetails: [ '1', '2', '3' ]
}
```

Now when you navigate to any of the views, you always push the same type of object as above. The views can select what they need from it. The drawback is you're keeping slightly more in memory.